# Populate ListView from Firebase, have the code but not receiving any data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the code from a previous project of mine to that can access Firebase & populate a list view from these values. The trouble is I no longer have this project so can't use it for reference.

The problem I'm having is that I'm receiving no objects returned from the db, so I can't set an onClickListener on nothin' .

Here is the code from the newsfeed class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://apintofplain.firebaseio.com/apintofplain/Drinks");
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference allBooksRef = rootRef.child("Drinks");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Drink> bookModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Drink book = ds.getValue(Drink.class);
                bookModelList.add(book);
            }
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            CustomListView adapter = new CustomListView(Feed.this, bookModelList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    allBooksRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);



    list.setClickable(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String make = pub[position];
            Toast.makeText(Feed.this, make, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Feed.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the code from my CustomListView class:

```
 public CustomListView(Feed feed, List<Drink> drinkList) {
    super(feed, R.layout.listview_layout, drinkList);

}
```

Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

[image]

```
String pub;
String location;
String price;
String rating;
String comment;
String signature;
String imageURL;

public Drink(){

}

public Drink(String pub, String location, String price, String rating, String comment, String signature, String imageURL){
    this.pub = pub;
    this.location = location;
    this.price = price;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.signature = signature;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}

public String getPub() {
    return pub;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public String getSignature() {
    return signature;
}

public String getImageURL(){
    return imageURL;
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added it above

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Drink` class.

Comment: @Alex Mamo , again updated above

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bookModelList.size()));` right after the for loops end, what is printed in the logcat?

Comment: @Alex Mamo - It says '3' , which is the correct number of records present in the db at the moment

Comment: I see now that your `CustomListView` is **not** complete.
Have you tried to use `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Feed.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bookModelList);` instead of `CustomListView adapter = new CustomListView(Feed.this, bookModelList);`? Does it work this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo - I get the error that says "Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter.."

Comment: Show me a [printscreen](https://imgbb.com/) of the error in code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188764/discussion-between-eoghan-casey-and-alex-mamo).